# How to call a function with in same java script file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am writing Automation scripts using protractor. I have created a java script file in which I have created a function.

PlatformviewCnOPage is my JS file and searchCapabilityOfferingsName is function. I want to call this function in another function (in same file).

```
var PlatformviewCnOPage = function() {

  this.searchCapabilityOfferingsName = function(){

    coreutil.clickElement(objectrepo.platformView_Searchbox_EnterBtn,'xpath');
    browser.sleep(2000);
    var searchResult= coreutil.getTextofElement(objectrepo.platformView_SearchResult,'xpath');
    return searchResult;
  }
```

I want to use the above function i.e searchCapabilityOfferingsName in another function in same java script file. I have tried some combinations but its not working.Basically I am new to java script.

```
 this.verifySearchinCnO = function(){

    this.searchCapabilityOfferingsName();// Failed-method not defined
    searchCapabilityOfferingsName(); //Failed method not defined
    Create object of same file and call the function. // Failed. 

  }

};
module.exports = PlatformviewCnOPage;
```

Could anyone suggest how can I call the function in another function in same JS file?

Answer (score 0):

PlatformviewCnOPage is defined as object/function which contains the method searchCapabilityOfferingsName.

So you can easily call PlatformviewCnOPage.searchCapabilityOfferingsName()

Comment: Tried this PlatformviewCnOPage.searchCapabilityOfferingsName() as well. But it says no definition found for searchCapabilityOfferingsName()

Comment: Wait, we have to create an instance of that class first...
So assign it to a variable for re-use and then call the method

`var p = new PlatformviewCnOPage();
p.searchCapabilityOfferingsName();`

- or -

`new PlatformviewCnOPage().searchCapabilityOfferingsName();`

Comment: HI Albert. Thanks for Replying. Actually I tried both. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some mistake in your PlatformviewCnOPage.js which lead to some definitions missing even loaded by `require`.

You can try below steps to figure out the wrong place:

**Step 1** comment out other codes only except function: `verifySearchinCnO` and `searchCapabilityOfferingsName`

**Step 2** add a `console.log(xxx)` as first line of the function: `verifySearchinCnO` and `searchCapabilityOfferingsName`

**Step 3** run your test script again, if the both `console.log(xxx)` print out,  means the wrong place in functions you commented out, then remove comment of some code lines and run test script again until find the correct place.